# Cross-platform toolkit definition: PhoneGap vs. Cordova

Tags: cordova, cross-platform

I'm trying to understand and work with cross-platform toolkits and recently discovered PhoneGap/Cordova. Here is my short approach describing these two:

> PhoneGap is owned by Adobe, Cordova is built on top of PhoneGap but is
>   open source and the community powered version of PhoneGap.

With that being said, I just want to know: when I talk about cross-platform toolkits, **which one of these two actually is a cross-platform toolkit?** Both of them? Why should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Is Adobe PhoneGap?

Adobe PhoneGap is nothing more than an implementation of Apache Cordova with some extra stuff
added to it. At its core is the Cordova container and API plugins.

As
Adobe’s primary business is in selling tools and services, the PhoneGap implementation of Cordova
more tightly integrates the framework with Adobe’s other products.
The primary differences between Cordova and PhoneGap are the command-line tools and the
PhoneGap Build service.

The PhoneGap command-line tools provide a
command-line interface into the PhoneGap Build service.

Throughout the remainder of the book, when I
refer to PhoneGap, I’m talking about a specific capability that is available only in the PhoneGap
version of Cordova. Both versions are free; PhoneGap simply adds some additional capabilities to
Cordova.

**From Apache Cordova 3 Programming book**

Comment: So that means that both Apache Cordova and Adobe PhoneGap are cross-platform toolkits, they just differ in functionality?

Comment: Yes, they are both cross-platforms toolkits and they are often confused. While they are free to use, if you want to deploy an app using Phonegap , there are license fees that you don't have with Cordova

Comment: I could send you the .pdf of the book if you are interested in. There are much more details